# C# mailkit shows error when inbox is empty

Tags: c#, mailkit

Below code works well, but the code will be checked every 5000ms, when the inbox folder is empty system shows an error.
We need to check inbox every 5000ms even it be empty we need to read it.

```
        using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            client.Connect(EXT_IMAP_SERVER, EXT_IMAP_PORT, true);

            client.Authenticate(EXT_USERNAME, EXT_PASSWORD);

            var inbox = client.Inbox;
            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
            var LAST_MSG = inbox.GetMessage (inbox.Count - 1);
          
            DATA = LAST_MSG.Subject;
        
            if(DATA != null); // this condition didn't solve our issue
            {
                inbox.AddFlags(inbox.Count - 1, MessageFlags.Deleted, true);
            }
        
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }

**ERROR:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'index')**
```

Comment: The error message is admirably clear. You're likely passing in `-1` to `GetMessage`.

Comment: Can you please, show me a sample code to solve it?

Comment: This -1 is for getting last message, when inbox is not empty it works, but when is empty... @tnw

Comment: I'm not super familiar with what you're doing but I'd add a condition like `if (inbox.Count == 0) //skip to disconnect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking if last message was null, check the `Count` of messages and if it's more than 0, then you do what you need to do.

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    client.Connect(EXT_IMAP_SERVER, EXT_IMAP_PORT, true);
    client.Authenticate(EXT_USERNAME, EXT_PASSWORD);

    var inbox = client.Inbox;
    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

    // THIS
    if(inbox.Count > 0) {
        var LAST_MSG = inbox.GetMessage (inbox.Count - 1);
        // .....
    }

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```